# Multiple Calls to RecyclerView Adapter notifyItemRangeChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a standard recyclerview that is split up into sections.
For simplicity, let's call them:

- Section A
- Section B
- Section C

When the recyclerview is loaded, I make network requests to fetch data. These network requests are triggered by the user reaching the first item in each section. Meaning, that there aren't three network requests triggered when the recyclerview is loaded, but rather only one.

Once I receive a response with data, I update the recyclerview using the [notifyItemRangeChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,int)) method.

When the user scrolls normally, this works flawlessly and I don't see any visible UI issues.

When the user scrolls really fast, from top to bottom, passing all the sections, the UI sometimes freezes all together. When looking at the code and narrowing down the problematic area, I found out that notifyItemRangeChanged is being called three times (as expected) in a very short time interval.

The calls themselves are at most 600 ms apart.

***(When I remove the calls to notifyItemRangeChanged, the UI doesn't get stuck)***

I understand that calling notifyItemRangeChanged has a costly impact on the UI due to it's inner logic and that is also why I am not calling notifyDataSetChanged.

But since I have not found a viable solution that listens in on when the recyclerview finishes updating the UI, I am wondering what I should be doing.

Nothing relevant or remotely close has come up in my searches.

How can I sync multiple calls to notifyItemRangeChanged? Or should I be using something else?

Comment: Do not call that method when you are yet waiting for another response.

Comment: But each request is triggered only when a user reaches the first item in a section. When a user scrolls fast and goes over all sections, requests are made and data is being returned. The responses are fairly quick so not waiting, will not give any buffering between the calls.

Comment: So you are saying that a response comes in before a next request can be done?

Comment: The responses aren't dependent on one another. The key here is if it is possible to synchronize calls to notifyItemRangeChanged.

Comment: Yes we know that. But if you dont give the info asked for then how can you be helped?

Comment: @blackapps - What information was asked???